# Finding probability from CDF

Tags: probability

Suppose that F is a cumulative distribution function where, 
$$F(x)=\begin{cases} 0,\text{if}\ x<0, \\ 1-e^{-x},\text{if}\ 0\le x<1, \\ c, \text{if}\ 1\le x<2,\\ 1-e^{-x}, \text{if}\   x\ge2, \end{cases}$$

1. Find all possible values of c.
2. Find $P(0.5\le X \le 2.5)$ and $P(X=1)+P(X=2)$.
   I think that the cdf should be right continuous and it is a continuous distribution (or is it mixed) so could this c have 2 values that are $1-e^-1$ and $1-e^-2$ but as the question is asking for discrete probabilities at X=1and2 then may be these are the two values at these two discrete points or are they zero? And the solution for$P(0.5\le X \le 2.5)$  must be $F(2.5)-F(.5)\\ =-e^-2.5+e^-.5$ please help me to understand the logic can be used to solve this question accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $F(x)$ is non-decreasing, we must have $c\ge \lim_{x\to 1^-} (1-e^{-x})$. So $c\ge 1-e^{-1}$.

A similar argument shows that $c\le 1-e^{-2}$. There are no other constraints on $c$.

Comment: @paw88789: We have $\Pr(0.5\le X\le 2.5)=e^{-0.5}-e^{-2.5}$. If you have uncertainty about the other probability, please leave a message.

Comment: So how should I get the probability at those discrete points 1 and 2 isn't paw88789  solution correct. I guess   even if $c$ is a constant we need to determine it so that we can get the above asked  probability if this limit thing is correct to find the probability at x=1 used in paw88789 answer

Comment: @Ab No, the value of c is not necessary to solve the exercise. Note that you are not asked to find P(X=1) and P(X=2) but P(X=1)+P(X=2).

Comment: @Abomm: We have $\Pr(X=1)=c-\lim_{x\to 1^-}(1-e^{-x})$, that is, $c-(1-e^{-1})$. For similar resons $\Pr(X=2)=(1-e^{-2})-c$. Add. It so happens that the $c$ cancels. If it didn't, it would not be a tragedy, the answer would be in terms of a $c$ that we know something about.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: And being mixed distribution doesn't affect the formula used for finding $P(.5\lex\le2.5)$?

Comment: It does not affect this probability. The probability is $\Pr(X\le 2.5)-\Pr(X\lt 0.5)$. The $\Pr(X\le 2.5)$ part is given directly by the cdf. As for $\Pr(X\lt 0.5)$, it is the same as $\Pr(X\le 0.5)$, since at $0.5$ we are in the interior of the continuous part of the cdf.